# MarkLogic: don't truncate error output?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Is there a way with ML to have it *not* truncate error output when using fn:error() or when an error is sent to the browser?   This is obviously for local development only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. However you can log messages in whatever detail you like with `xdmp:log`, `fn:trace`, and `xdmp:trace`. When doing this, `xdmp:describe` and `xdmp:quote` are also useful.

http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:log

Comment: You can write a custom error page per http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/appserver-control#id_75119 – but its input `$error:errors` variable contains the same truncated XML that you see in the default output. To display non-truncated data you would have to find a way to get back to the original data and use it to build the output that you want. There might be some way to do that using http://docs.marklogic.com/dbg - but it would be difficult and might prove impossible. The custom error page may not run in the same request, and if it doesn't how would you identify the original request?

Comment: To save anyone else the trouble, I've confirmed that the error page runs in a separate request and that the original request is no longer available. So I don't see how a custom error page could be made to undo any truncation in the error XML.

Comment: How did you verify that?  (Just curious.)

Comment: With `xdmp:request`, `xdmp:log`, and `xdmp:server-status`.